# bubble cloud - componente/plugin jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, componentes, nuvem-de-tags

[image: bubble cloud]

Car@s, preciso de um plugin/complemento jquery para fazer uma bubble cloud como esta. Sugestões? Valeu.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada nesse: [https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) ?<br>
Não testei, mas parece bem parecido com o que você procura.